# linux diff tools: create list of modified files

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, diff

How do I create a list of modified files programmatically using linux command line tools? I'm not interested in the difference in any particular file (delta, patch). I just want to have a list of new or modified files comparing to previous product release. So that I can publish a new product update.

update: `diff -qr` doesn't produce very convinient output. The output of `diff -qr` also needs to be processed. Is there any better way?

Comment: what's an example of "convenient" output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I`ve got a simple approach for this:
Use the rsync-preview mode:

```
rsync -aHSvn --delete old_dir/ new-dir/
```

The files that are shown as "to be deleted" by that command will be the "new" files. The others that are to be transferred have changed in some way. See the rsync-man-page for further details.

Comment: Careful with this : rsync will not actually compare the content of the files. As per the man page, "rsync uses a lqquick checkrq that (by default) checks if each file's size and time of last modification match between the sender and receiver" (https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) ; you might want to use -c (--checksum) option that compares the files based on a checksum, although "this can slow things down significantly"

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [diff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) toool: see the options -q and -r

```
-q  --brief
Output only whether files differ.

-r  --recursive
Recursively compare any subdirectories found.
```

Example:

```
diff -qr dir1 dir2
```

Comment: Absolutely awful and unreadable output, cluttered with nonsense information saying `Only in` which does appears even if the directories are ideal copies. I was needed to compare changes against an old revision, and end up downloading whole revision into a separate directory, and using standard SVN tools to compare. That seems the only way to go…

Answer (score 3):

The `diffutils` package includes a `lsdiff` tool. Just pass the output of `diff -u` to lsdiff:

```
diff -u --other-diff-options path1 path2 | lsdiff
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thank you. Was in the `patchutils` package for me (CentOS 5.x).

Comment: Yep, patchutils package for Ubuntu/Debian, too.

Answer (score 2):

To take only the name of files that they changed, I use this command:

```
diff -r dirt1 dir2 --brief | sed 's/^Only in \([^:]*\): /\1\//' | sed 's/^Files \(.*\) and .* differ/\1/'
```

If need to exclude some files as object files or library files, you could use:

```
diff -r dirt1 dir2 --brief --exclude "*.o" --exclude "*.a" | sed 's/^Only in \([^:]*\): /\1\//' | sed 's/^Files \(.*\) and .* differ/\1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a list of new or modified files programmatically the best solution I could come up with is using **rsync**, **sort**, and **uniq**:

```
(rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" old/ new/ && rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" new/ old/) | sort | uniq
```

Let me explain with this example: we want to compare two dokuwiki releases to see which files were changed and which ones were newly created.

We fetch the tars with wget and extract them into the directories `old/` and `new/`:

```
wget http://download.dokuwiki.org/src/dokuwiki/dokuwiki-2014-09-29d.tgz
wget http://download.dokuwiki.org/src/dokuwiki/dokuwiki-2014-09-29.tgz
mkdir old && tar xzf dokuwiki-2014-09-29.tgz -C old --strip-components=1
mkdir new && tar xzf dokuwiki-2014-09-29d.tgz -C new --strip-components=1
```

Running rsync one way might miss newly created files as the comparison of rsync and diff shows here:

```
rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" old/ new/
```

*yields the following output:*

```
VERSION
doku.php
conf/mime.conf
inc/auth.php
inc/lang/no/lang.php
lib/plugins/acl/remote.php
lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php
lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php
```

Running rsync only in one direction misses the newly created files and the other way round would miss deleted files, compare the output of diff:

```
diff -qr old/ new/
```

*yields the following output:*

```
Files old/VERSION and new/VERSION differ
Files old/conf/mime.conf and new/conf/mime.conf differ
Only in new/data/pages: playground
Files old/doku.php and new/doku.php differ
Files old/inc/auth.php and new/inc/auth.php differ
Files old/inc/lang/no/lang.php and new/inc/lang/no/lang.php differ
Files old/lib/plugins/acl/remote.php and new/lib/plugins/acl/remote.php differ
Files old/lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php and new/lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php differ
Files old/lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php and new/lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php differ
```

Running rsync both ways and sorting the output to remove duplicates reveals that the directory `data/pages/playground/` and the file `data/pages/playground/playground.txt` were missed initially:

```
(rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" old/ new/ && rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" new/ old/) | sort | uniq
```

*yields the following output:*

```
VERSION
conf/mime.conf
data/pages/playground/
data/pages/playground/playground.txt
doku.php
inc/auth.php
inc/lang/no/lang.php
lib/plugins/acl/remote.php
lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php
lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php
```

`rsync` is run with theses arguments:

- `-r` to "recurse into directories",
- `-c` to also compare files of identical size and only "skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size",
- `-n` to "perform a trial run with no changes made", and
- `--out-format="%n"` to "output updates using the specified FORMAT", which is "%n" here for the file name only

The output (list of files) of `rsync` in both directions is combined and sorted using `sort`, and this sorted list is then condensed by removing all duplicates with `uniq`

Answer (score 1):

I would just touch a file at the time of each update, and then you can find files that were modified since then with `find /tree/location -newer /last/update/file -print`

Answer (score 1):

You should get desired result using:

```
diff -r --brief dir1/ dir2/
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you put the files into some kind of version control system like SubVersion or git, since those can do this for you out of the box.

But you could do a quick script with a for loop on dir1 and then compare every file with the one in dir2. The for loop can look at the exit code from diff to know if the files was different.

Maybe something like this:

```
for f in `(cd dir1 ; find .)`
do 
  diff $f ../dir2/$f
  if [ "$?" == "0" ]
  then 
    echo same
  else 
    echo diff: $f
  fi
done
```

**Note:** Script is not tested, so the above example is "bash inspired pseudocode"...

---

Let's take another go but with git

Create some example files to play with

```
mkdir -p dir1/test1/test11
mkdir -p dir1/test1/test12
mkdir -p dir1/test1/test13
echo "Test1" >> dir1/test1/test11/t1.txt
echo "Test2" >> dir1/test1/test12/t2.txt
echo "Test3" >> dir1/test1/test13/t3.txt

#And a dir to work in
mkdir gitdir
```

Then enter the dir and import dir1

```
cd gitdir/
git init .
cp -r ../dir1/* .
git add .
git commit -m 'dir1'
```

Go out and modify dir1 (so it becomes your dir2)

```
cd ..
echo "Test2" > dir1/test1/test11/t1.txt
```

Then go into the git dir and import the new dir

```
cd gitdir/
cp -r ../dir1/* .
```

Now ask git what has change (with the status command)

```
git status -s
```

The output is a list with the changes, that looks like this:

```
 M test1/test11/t1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.bash_aliases#L231) might do the trick:

```
compare_dirs()
{
    # Shows which files and directories exist in one directory but not both
    if [ $# -ne 2 ]
    then
        echo "Usage: compare_dirs dir1 dir2" >&2
        return 2
    fi
    for path
    do
        if [ ! -d "$path" ]
        then
            echo "Not a directory: $path" >&2
            return 1
        fi
    done
    comm -3 \
        <(cd -- "$1" && find . -printf '%P\0' | sort -z | quote_shell) \
        <(cd -- "$2" && find . -printf '%P\0' | sort -z | quote_shell)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd be happier with something different. Try [`git`](http://git-scm.com/).

Do this as an example:

```
mkdir a
cd a
git init
touch b
git add . && git commit -m "Empty file"
git status
echo c >> b
git status
git add . && git commit -m "Full file"
git status
```

`git` will track your files for you. The command `git status` will show you all the files that have been modified since the last commit.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to *[rsync: show when newer file on destination is to be overwritten](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239684/rsync-show-when-newer-file-on-destination-is-to-be-overwritten)* (asked later, though not a duplicate).

As indicated in the question, "diff -q -r" may require some processing to be useful.  The question did not specify the form of the output; the answers give different types of reports.

`rsync` is a useful tool for this purpose because it is ***much*** faster than `diff`.  However the solution suggested by @nils is far more verbose (and lists more files) than the actual differences between the old/new directory trees.  For example, comparing that against the script which I wrote for that answer, and running on the same data,

- @nils answer produces 605 lines (apparently because it includes *directory* changes),
- "diff -q -r" produces 352 lines after running for several minutes, and
- my script shows 252 lines (***actual*** files changed, added or deleted)

To make `diff` properly account for *new* files, you need the `-N` option as well (which I do not see in any of the suggested answers).  However, since it is far slower (orders of magnitude) than `rsync`, improving the latter's output seems the way to go.

Further reading

- [diff - compare files line by line](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)
- [rsync -- a fast, versatile, remote (and local) file-copying tool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Answer (score 0):

I've always been partial to sha1sum (or even md5sum; in this context it's quite safe).

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort -k2 > /tmp/before
# don't miss the "sort" in there; it's important

# (later)
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort -k2 > /tmp/after
vimdiff /tmp/before /tmp/after
# or whatever diff tool you like, even "diff -u"
```

Sometimes -- like if you have too many files being renamed or moved about -- sorting on the first field and then doing the diff could help, but most of the time this is good enough.

Note that, compared to some of the other methods, this has the advantage that you don't need to keep a copy of the "before" files; only the md5sum output file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet to clean up the output of `diff -q` (just going a little further @Felicia Barcelo's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87564/240881), which should be the approved answer by the way)

> Note that `rsync` does not actually compare files by their content

Suppose you want to compare `dir1` and `dir2` such as :

```
dir1                   # older version of something
  - sub1
  - sub2
  - irrelevant
dir2                   # newer version
  - sub1
  - sub2
```

```
diff -rqi -x 'irrelevant' dir1 dir2 \
| sed -E -e 's/Files .* and (.*) differ/Changed : \1/g' \
         -e 's#Only in (dir1/.*): (.*)#Removed : \1/\2#g' \
         -e 's#Only in (dir2/.*): (.*)#New : \1/\2#g\' \
| sort -u
```

- the `\` at the end of each line allows to enter a command on several lines
- `diff -rqi --color=never`
  compare recursively, ignoring case, showing only which files differ
- `-x 'irrelevant'` (or `--exclude='irrelevant'`)
  ignore subdir `irrelevant` (could be some cache or `.git` or whatever)
- `sed -E`
  use `sed` to process output with extended regexp
- `-e 's/Files .* and (.*) differ/Changed : \1/g'`
  output files that differ as `Changed: dir2/filename`
- `-e 's#Only in (dir1/.*): (.*)#Removed : \1/\2#g'`
  output files that exist only in `dir1` as `Removed: dir1/filename`
- `-e 's#Only in (dir2/.*): (.*)#New : \1/\2#g\'`
  output files that exist only in `dir2` as `New: dir2/filename`
- `sort -u`
  sort output so you have `Changed`, `New` and `Removed` files grouped together

You can output the list to a file by redirecting the output with  `> diff.list` but you'll need to add `--color=never` to the `diff` command in order to avoid escape characters :

```
diff -rqi --color=never -x 'irrelevant' dir1 dir2 \
| sed -E -e 's/Files .* and (.*) differ/Changed : \1/g' \
         -e 's#Only in (dir1/.*): (.*)#Removed : \1/\2#g' \
         -e 's#Only in (dir2/.*): (.*)#New : \1/\2#g\' \
| sort -u > diff.list
```