# rsync: show when newer file on destination is to be overwritten

Tags: rsync

I'm running a command that updates some files to a centralized server.
The command does first a `--dry-run` to show which files will be transferred.
It may happen that a newer file on server may have to be overwritten - and I'd like the `rsync --dry-run` command to show specifically when it is the case.

Currently the rsync command looks like

```
rsync -aviO sdir/ ddir
```

Say the command produces the output

```
 >f.st...... file-newer-on-source
 >f.st...... file-newer-on-destination
```

for the sake of clarity, doing `rsync -aviuO sdir/ ddir` (--update) produces, normally,

```
 >f.st...... file-newer-on-source
```

But I'd like the command to show when a file is to be overwritten while being newer! Currently there is no distinction in the output between `file-newer-on-source` and `...-destination`. Something like this would be great

```
 >f.st...... file-newer-on-source
 >f.sT...... file-newer-on-destination
```

but that's not the case.

Is there another option, or a `out-format` setup that would show specifically that a **newer** file is to be overwritten?

Answer (score 4):

The place to look would be in the `-v` (verbose) option, which can be repeated.  That does not give exactly the requested information.

However, you can construct what is wanted by running the different parts using other options (see [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)):

> -u, --update
>                 skip files that are newer on the receiver
>
> --existing
>               skip creating new files on receiver
>
> --ignore-existing
>        skip updating files that exist on receiver

Here is an example, using `-u` and `--existing`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: check-rsync,v 1.3 2022/10/11 20:02:24 tom Exp $
# Make a readable report showing whether files would be added (+), deleted (-),
# updated (>) or downdated (<) using rsync between two directories.
#
# Updates to directories are ignored.
#
# author: Thomas E. Dickey (2015)

usage() {
    cat >&2 <<-EOF
    usage: check-rsync [-d] [source] [target]
EOF
    exit 1
}

OPTS=
while [ $# != 0 ]
do
    case .$1 in
    (.-*)
        OPTS="$OPTS $1"
        shift 1
        ;;
    (*)
        break
        ;;
    esac
done

[ $# = 2 ] || usage
[ -d "$1" ] || usage
[ -d "$2" ] || usage

LANG=C
export LANG

SOURCE=$1
TARGET=$2

MYTEMP=$(mktemp -d)
trap "cd; rm -rf $MYTEMP" EXIT

syncit() {
    rsync "$@" -n -vaz --delete $OPTS "$SOURCE"/ "$TARGET" | \
        sed -e '/^\(sending\|sent\|total\) /d' \
            -e '/^$/d' \
            -e '/^\.\//d' \
            -e '/\/$/d' | \
        sort
}

cd "$MYTEMP" || exit

syncit              >all-updates
syncit -u           >was-newer
syncit --existing       >was-existing

comm -23 all-updates was-existing | \
    sed -e '/^deleting /d' \
        -e 's/^/+ /' >>report
comm -23 all-updates was-newer | \
    sed -e '/^deleting /d' \
        -e 's/^/< /' >>report
sed -e 's/^deleting /- /' -e t -e d all-updates >>report

comm -12 all-updates was-newer | \
    sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]\+//' \
        -e '/^deleting /d' -e 's/^/> /' >>report

sort -k2 report
```

I used this to compare two local directory-trees (about 10,000 files with about 100 changes).  The script explicitly checks that its parameters are directories.  That check would be modified for use with remote systems, but since the question relates to how to use `rsync` options, rather than basic shell-scripting, that change is not part of this example.

The third option would be useful if one extended the script to show = for unchanged files. But I have no practical use for that: leave it as an exercise for the reader.

Sample output:

```
+ anon_ftp/pub/xterm/current/xterm-374.tgz
> anon_ftp/pub/xterm/current/xterm-374.tgz
+ anon_ftp/pub/xterm/current/xterm-374.tgz.asc
> anon_ftp/pub/xterm/current/xterm-374.tgz.asc
> anon_ftp/pub/xterm/current/xterm.tar.gz -> xterm-374.tgz
+ anon_ftp/pub/xterm/patches/xterm-374.patch.gz
> anon_ftp/pub/xterm/patches/xterm-374.patch.gz
+ anon_ftp/pub/xterm/patches/xterm-374.patch.gz.asc
> anon_ftp/pub/xterm/patches/xterm-374.patch.gz.asc
+ anon_ftp/pub/xterm/xterm-374.tgz
> anon_ftp/pub/xterm/xterm-374.tgz
+ anon_ftp/pub/xterm/xterm-374.tgz.asc
> anon_ftp/pub/xterm/xterm-374.tgz.asc
> anon_ftp/pub/xterm/xterm.tar.gz -> xterm-374.tgz
+ httpdocs/archives/xterm/current/xterm-374.tgz
> httpdocs/archives/xterm/current/xterm-374.tgz
+ httpdocs/archives/xterm/current/xterm-374.tgz.asc
> httpdocs/archives/xterm/current/xterm-374.tgz.asc
> httpdocs/archives/xterm/current/xterm.tar.gz -> xterm-374.tgz
+ httpdocs/archives/xterm/patches/xterm-374.patch.gz
> httpdocs/archives/xterm/patches/xterm-374.patch.gz
+ httpdocs/archives/xterm/patches/xterm-374.patch.gz.asc
> httpdocs/archives/xterm/patches/xterm-374.patch.gz.asc
+ httpdocs/archives/xterm/xterm-374.tgz
> httpdocs/archives/xterm/xterm-374.tgz
+ httpdocs/archives/xterm/xterm-374.tgz.asc
> httpdocs/archives/xterm/xterm-374.tgz.asc
> httpdocs/archives/xterm/xterm.tar.gz -> xterm-374.tgz
> httpdocs/datafiles/current/xterm.tar.gz
> httpdocs/datafiles/release/xterm.tar.gz
> httpdocs/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs-contents.html
> httpdocs/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html
> httpdocs/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf
> httpdocs/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.ps
> httpdocs/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.txt
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/koi8rxterm.html
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/koi8rxterm.pdf
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/koi8rxterm.ps
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/koi8rxterm.txt
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/resize.html
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/resize.pdf
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/resize.ps
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/resize.txt
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/uxterm.html
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/uxterm.pdf
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/uxterm.ps
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/uxterm.txt
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/xterm-contents.html
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/xterm.html
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/xterm.pdf
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/xterm.ps
> httpdocs/xterm/manpage/xterm.txt
> httpdocs/xterm/terminfo-contents.html
> httpdocs/xterm/terminfo-entries.html
> httpdocs/xterm/terminfo-header.html
> httpdocs/xterm/terminfo.html
> httpdocs/xterm/xterm.log.html
> logs/access_log
> logs/access_log.processed
> logs/access_log.webstat
> logs/access_ssl_log
> logs/access_ssl_log.processed
> logs/access_ssl_log.webstat
> logs/error_log
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_log
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_log.processed
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_log.webstat
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_ssl_log
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_ssl_log.processed
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_ssl_log.processed.1.gz
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_ssl_log.processed.2.gz
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_ssl_log.processed.3.gz
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_ssl_log.processed.4.gz
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_ssl_log.processed.5.gz
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/access_ssl_log.webstat
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/error_log
> logs/lynx.invisible-island.net/proxy_access_ssl_log
> logs/proxy_access_log
> logs/proxy_access_ssl_log
> logs/proxy_error_log
> logs/xferlog
> logs/xferlog.processed
> logs/xferlog.webstat
```

Comment: Even the highest `v` level doesn't give that information, unfortunately. And the 3 options are irrelevant.

Comment: The `sync` function appears to ignore its arguments. The loop creating `OPTS` may not terminate (lacks a `shift`). Also, the `OPTS` variable should probably be an array (the interpreter would need to change from `sh` though), or you could just supplement the list of positional parameters when calling your `syncit` function without needing to parse the command line at all (there's actually no need to pick out the source or target arguments). A few expansions lack quoting.

Comment: yes... too long ago to recall, but it seems that in refactoring it for reuse, I omitted the `"@"`.  updating...