# rsync --verbose always shows directory structure when syncing to NTFS volume

Tags: rsync, ntfs

When you run rsync with the -v option, for example

```
rsync -av "/from/this/dir/" "/to/this/dir"
```

... you will get a list of what was updated/deleted etc. So, the first run will give you a bunch of inserted/deleted/updated entries, and if no changes were made to the source dir - subsequent runs will give you something like this:

```
sending incremental file list

sent 431 bytes  received 18 bytes  898.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

That's all fine and dandy!

However, when I rsync to a directory on a mounted NTFS volume, rsync will *always*, on *every single subsequent run* show *every single directory*, even though no action was made whatsoever, no updates, no deletes, no inserts, no nothing.

I don't want to see rsync traverse through the directory structure every single run, but I DO want to see the updates.

What gives?

Comment: See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239684/rsync-show-when-newer-file-on-destination-is-to-be-overwritten/239711#239711).

Comment: You can change the output format, search the manual for `--info`, `--itemize-changes` and `--out-format`.

Comment: Some filesystems don't hold as much detailed info as ext3 or 4, so when you redo an `rsync -a` it may find differences that it can never fix.  FAT for example holds timestamps with a granularity of 2 seconds.

Comment: If it is a timestamp resolution problem, you might be able to solve it by adding something like `--modify-window=1` (which makes it treat timestamps within one second as matches).